# Sun CodeModel generic method

Tags: java, generics, sun-codemodel

Does anyone know how to generate the following generic method declaration using CodeModel?

```
public <T> T getValue(Class<T> clazz){...}
```

usage:

```
ValueType value = getValue(ValueType.class);
```

Seems not to be handled by the existing implementation.

I know I could handle the code as follows, but it requires a cast:

```
public Object getValue(Class class){...}
```

usage:

```
ValueType value = (ValueType)getValue(ValueType.class);
```

Obviously, this is a bit messy because of the cast.

Comment: Interesting, just found a bug report that mentions this issue: http://java.net/jira/browse/CODEMODEL-4 .  Plus, this was commented on recently.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Create the method with an `Object` return type, generify the method, then overwrite the return type.

```
final JDefinedClass exampleClass = codeModel._class( "com.example.ExampleClass" );
final JMethod method = exampleClass.method( JMod.PUBLIC, Object.class, "getValue" );
final JTypeVar t = method.generify( "T" );
method.type( t );
method.param( codeModel.ref( Class.class ).narrow( t ), "type" );
method.body()._return(JExpr._null());
```

Comment: This works like a charm.  Thank you so much for setting me on the right path.  I've taken the liberty of updating the referenced jira issue.